# How to check if a variable contains a date or a date and text?

Tags: php

How to check whether a variable `$date` contains a date in the form of *2011-09-20* ? This is to know if the `$date` contains any letters in it because I want to use the `date()` and gives me error.

Comment: Why do you want to limit yourself to the format '2011-09-20'? What's wrong with '20-09-2011'? Being from outside the United States, I can tell you it's very frustrating to get errors because I'm using a date in a format other than the one the US uses. strtotime( ) accepts all date formats, please don't ruin your software for me ;)

Comment: I am outside of the US too. However the product I use is in from the US.

Comment: I add one demo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645094/how-to-check-if-a-variable-contains-a-date-or-a-date-and-text/7645146#7645146

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this:

```
$date = '2011-09-20';
list($y, $m, $d) = explode("-", $date);
if(checkdate($m, $d, $y)){
    echo "OK Date";
} else {
    echo "BAD Date";
}
```

demo here: http://codepad.org/3iqrQrey

Comment: Just a suggestion to avoid non-well formated error when try to parse a variable with string content:
`if(is_numeric($y) && is_numeric($m) && is_numeric($d) && checkdate($m, $d, $y)){`

Answer (score 9):

One approch would be this though it's not perfect.

```
if (false === strtotime($date)) {
    echo 'invalid date';
else {
    echo 'valid date';
}
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with it? I think this is the perfect way, allowing all possible date formats.

Comment: well, strtotime('now') will return a timestamp and that's not what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

This is not exatly what you ask for (will also accept other date formats) but will help to find out date is valid:
`strtotime($date)` will return `FALSE` if `$date` has invalid date format.
[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you try the [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) in combination with the [str_replace()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method, like so:

```
<?php
  $isValid = is_numeric(str_replace('-', '', $myDateToCheck));
?>
```

Of course, this does not say anything about the format of the date but is does give an indication whether the variable contains any non-numeric characters.

If the above example returns true, you might want to use the [checkdate()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) method to further investigate your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a regular expression (`^[1-9]{4}-[1-9]{2}-[1-9]{2}$`) with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php) for this.

Another way would be [`strptime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php), which is used to convert a string (associated with a certain format) to a time.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

Combining what @Alfwed and @JellyBelly wrote, here's how I did it:

```
public function valid_date($inputdate){
    $date = $inputdate;
    if (strtotime($date)){
       if (strpos($date,'/') !== false) {
         list($day, $month, $year) = explode('/', $date);
         return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
       }else{
            return false;
       }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will check wether if the input is text (e.g: "adasdsad"), or if it has a date format (e.g: "10/02/1988"), and it checks if it's a valid date.

If input date is 10-10-1996 which is also a valid format, or 10.02.1996, it won't accept them because I'm asking the user to use the format with "/". Just remove the if it if you don't want to do this validation and that is it.

**SOLUTION 2**

I have found that solution 1 doesn't work if you plan to enter a future date. So I had to find another solution. Here it is:

```
    public function valid_date($date, $format = 'd/m/Y'){
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

It's not mine, found it at: [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.checkdate.php)